# What is this style of writing where some words are off-center?

Tags: songs

I've noticed in a few Chinese songs that, when the lyrics take up multiple lines, the second line will be shifted to the right or off-center.

The biggest example of this is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2601BDvx2U

If you skip around the video you'll see what I mean- there's a lot of spacing between words, and in this example they even confine it to a grid.

Is there a name for this? Is it an old Chinese writing practice? I feel like I've noticed it in quite a few songs now.

Thank you! Also heads up I know no Chinese

Comment: It has nothing to do with Chinese, It is just an artistic choice of the subtitle editor. Maybe he though it would make the subtitle look more 'organic'  than 'mechanic'

Comment: Even on the video I linked?

Comment: Even on the video I linked?  Yes.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a writing style, rather it is a style of arranging letters to be an artistic presentation for the fun/pleasure of viewing.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am from China and I can make sure that we does not have some writing habit to shift second line to right or off-center when writing articles or lyrics.

The reason why to write like this in the video, is just for making it beautiful.

> when the lyrics take up multiple lines

In the video you linked, the lyrics actually just have one line but split into multiple lines deliberately.